# Decode a wordpress theme

Tags: decode, decoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP decode starting with $OOO000000=urldecode('%66%67%36%73%62%65%68%70%72%61%34%63](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700767/php-decode-starting-with-ooo000000-urldecode6667367362656870726134)

This wordpress theme can get a big 10 on evil scale. The functions.php file is fully encoded so as you can't get rid of the footer link. But it also prevent us to improve the theme and that's a shame.

So, anyone can decode this ? I tried with online decoders, can't get it right.
Thanks a lot !

```
<?php /*  */$OOO000000=urldecode('%66%67%36%73%62%65%68%70%72%61%34%63%6f%5f%74%6e%64');$OOO0000O0=$OOO000000{4}.$OOO000000{9}.$OOO000000{3}.$OOO000000{5};$OOO0000O0.=$OOO000000{2}.$OOO000000{10}.$OOO000000{13}.$OOO000000{16};$OOO0000O0.=$OOO0000O0{3}.$OOO000000{11}.$OOO000000{12}.$OOO0000O0{7}.$OOO000000{5};$OOO000O00=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{12}.$OOO000000{7}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{15};$O0O000O00=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{1}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{14};$O0O000O0O=$O0O000O00.$OOO000000{11};$O0O000O00=$O0O000O00.$OOO000000{3};$O0O00OO00=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{8}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{9}.$OOO000000{16};$OOO00000O=$OOO000000{3}.$OOO000000{14}.$OOO000000{8}.$OOO000000{14}.$OOO000000{8};$OOO0O0O00=__FILE__;$OO00O0000=0x908;eval($OOO0000O0('JE8wMDBPME8wMD0kT09PMDAwTzAwKCRPT08wTzBPMDAsJ3JiJyk7JE8wTzAwT08wMCgkTzAwME8wTzAwLDB4NDgxKTskT08wME8wME8wPSRPT08wMDAwTzAoJE9PTzAwMDAwTygkTzBPMDBPTzAwKCRPMDAwTzBPMDAsMHgxN2MpLCdzME1PZzRjbGRIMXVtRUtxL1lRb3hiQlpTOHlGMkphUmpQTDUzcjlBeitlQzdVR3ZocElUbjZ0TmZWaVhEd2tXPScsJ0FCQ0RFRkdISUpLTE1OT1BRUlNUVVZXWFlaYWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXowMTIzNDU2Nzg5Ky8nKSk7ZXZhbCgkT08wME8wME8wKTs='));return;?>f]pDOJwHgwqmO0qmO0qmO6TJlHR29bhFc458QjAZ6wcQxp4Z6DAuMdAdLf3onwqmgDhoTshuLdAdLh3onwqmOshmgDh1MYqonDhmOshmgDzHgDhoTshonDhmMj3oTshmgDhoTshuMYqoTshoTshmOs+uMJTmg6q8TY5FcYdmZbUYxUpu6rYFNPL/r+oKlrcm3+Px9+/oOxT25r0aLUr/TJbYN8z2grxF58no98BybPgJtUZqQ27Hn4M/nY4Y3JdQx+uog6Ko60YxrExbb8ZB4rySBH58cb98tP+y9U7FBVv2l4I2NY6JAJfaZzhmodTEOxtETjV1IDA1Q3+Kt85FcwT8Qj3oTshmgDhoTsh1oUrJ9471MYqoTshoTshoTs+Kh==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
```

Answer (score 1):

Examine this line:

```
$OOO000000 = urldecode('%66%67%36%73%62%65%68%70%72%61%34%63%6f%5f%74%6e%64');
```

Decode that [here](http://www.albionresearch.com/misc/urlencode.php)

```
$OOO000000 = 'fg6sbehpra4co_tnd';
```

Then take the next line:

```
$OOO0000O0 = $OOO000000{4}.$OOO000000{9}.$OOO000000{3}.$OOO000000{5};
```

Which basically says take character 4, 9, 3, 5 from that string (index starting from 0), so we get...

```
$OOO0000O0 = 'base';
```

Now try the rest yourself.

---

Start by make the code a little more readable:

```
<?php 

$OOO000000=urldecode('%66%67%36%73%62%65%68%70%72%61%34%63%6f%5f%74%6e%64');

$OOO0000O0=$OOO000000{4}.$OOO000000{9}.$OOO000000{3}.$OOO000000{5};

$OOO0000O0.=$OOO000000{2}.$OOO000000{10}.$OOO000000{13}.$OOO000000{16};

$OOO0000O0.=$OOO0000O0{3}.$OOO000000{11}.$OOO000000{12}.$OOO0000O0{7}.$OOO000000{5};

$OOO000O00=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{12}.$OOO000000{7}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{15};

$O0O000O00=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{1}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{14};

$O0O000O0O=$O0O000O00.$OOO000000{11};

$O0O000O00=$O0O000O00.$OOO000000{3};

$O0O00OO00=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{8}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{9}.$OOO000000{16};

$OOO00000O=$OOO000000{3}.$OOO000000{14}.$OOO000000{8}.$OOO000000{14}.$OOO000000{8};

$OOO0O0O00=__FILE__;

$OO00O0000=0x908;

eval($OOO0000O0('JE8wMDBPME8wMD0kT09PMDAwTzAwKCRPT08wTzBPMDAsJ3JiJyk7JE8wTzAwT08wMCgkTzAwME8wTzAwLDB4NDgxKTskT08wME8wME8wPSRPT08wMDAwTzAoJE9PTzAwMDAwTygkTzBPMDBPTzAwKCRPMDAwTzBPMDAsMHgxN2MpLCdzME1PZzRjbGRIMXVtRUtxL1lRb3hiQlpTOHlGMkphUmpQTDUzcjlBeitlQzdVR3ZocElUbjZ0TmZWaVhEd2tXPScsJ0FCQ0RFRkdISUpLTE1OT1BRUlNUVVZXWFlaYWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXowMTIzNDU2Nzg5Ky8nKSk7ZXZhbCgkT08wME8wME8wKTs='));

return;

?>

f]pDOJwHgwqmO0qmO0qmO6TJlHR29bhFc458QjAZ6wcQxp4Z6DAuMdAdLf3onwqmgDhoTshuLdAdLh3onwqmOshmgDh1MYqonDhmOshmgDzHgDhoTshonDhmMj3oTshmgDhoTshuMYqoTshoTshmOs+uMJTmg6q8TY5FcYdmZbUYxUpu6rYFNPL/r+oKlrcm3+Px9+/oOxT25r0aLUr/TJbYN8z2grxF58no98BybPgJtUZqQ27Hn4M/nY4Y3JdQx+uog6Ko60YxrExbb8ZB4rySBH58cb98tP+y9U7FBVv2l4I2NY6JAJfaZzhmodTEOxtETjV1IDA1Q3+Kt85FcwT8Qj3oTshmgDhoTsh1oUrJ9471MYqoTshoTshoTs+Kh==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
```

Then change `eval` to `echo eval`. I think that should at least get you started.

Comment: Thanks ! You answered so quick, but what to you mean by eval to echo eval ? And, what is the next step after this ?

Comment: People on stackoverflow are here to guide and assist you, not do your work for you. If you don't understand the difference between `eval` and `echo eval`, you need to hire someone who does.

Comment: So i got : Base 64_d scope fopen fget c s fread strtr. I'm starting to get the point, that's very interersting.

Comment: I just want to learn, not to make people work for me :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

if (function_exists('register_sidebar'))
        register_sidebar(array(
            'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget' => '</li>',
            'before_title' => '',
            'after_title' => '<br />',
        ));

function widget_yes_search() {
        ;
        echo '      
        ';
        _e('Search');
        ;
        echo '          <form id="searchform" method="get" action="';
        echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        ;
        echo '">
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="s" id="s" size="15" /><br />
                ';
        ;
        echo '          </div>
        </form>
';
}

if (function_exists('register_sidebar_widget'))
        register_sidebar_widget(__('Search'), 'widget_yes_search');

function GET_F0OTER() {
        ;
        echo '      

            <div id="credit">
                &copy; ';
        echo date('Y');
        ;
        echo ' ';
        bloginfo('name');
        ;
        echo '. All right reserved.<br />
                Designed by <a href="http://www.dc-photographic.co.uk/">Duncan Cox</a>
            </div>
            </div>
</body>
</html>

';
}

function getImage($num) {
        global $more;
        $more = 1;
        $content = get_the_content();
        $count = substr_count($content, '<img');
        $start = 0;
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
                $imgBeg = strpos($content, '<img', $start);
                $post = substr($content, $imgBeg);
                $imgEnd = strpos($post, '>');
                $postOutput = substr($post, 0, $imgEnd + 1);
                $image[$i] = $postOutput;
                $start = $imgEnd + 1;
                $cleanF = strpos($image[$num], 'src="') + 5;
                $cleanB = strpos($image[$num], '"', $cleanF) - $cleanF;
                $imgThumb = substr($image[$num], $cleanF, $cleanB);
        }
        if (stristr($image[$num], '<img')) {
                echo $imgThumb;
        }
        $more = 0;
}

function cats_meow($glue) {
        $current_cat = single_cat_title('', false);
        $separator = "\n";
        $cats = explode($separator, get_the_category_list($separator));
        foreach ($cats as $i => $str) {
                if (strstr($str, ">$current_cat<")) {
                        unset($cats[$i]);
                        break;
                }
        }
        if (empty($cats))
                return false;
        return trim(join($glue, $cats));
}
```

Comment: How did you do that??